# "Reverse formatting" Riak search results

Tags: riak, riak-search

Let's say I have an object in the `test` bucket in my Riak installation with the following structure:

```
{
    "animals": {
        "dog": "woof",
        "cat: "miaow",
        "cow": "moo"
    }
}
```

When performing a search request for this object, the structure of the search results is as follows:

```
{
    "responseHeader": {
        "status": 0,
        "QTime": 3,
        "params": {
            "q": "animals_cow:moo",
            "q.op": "or",
            "filter":"",
            "wt": "json"
        }
    },
    "response": {
        "numFound": 1,
        "start": 0,
        "maxScore": "0.353553",
        "docs": [
            {
                "id": "test",
                "index": "test",
                "fields": {
                    "animals_cat": "miaow",
                    "animals_cow": "moo",
                    "animals_dog": "woof"
                },
                "props": {}
            }
        ]
    }
}
```

As you can see, the way the object is stored, the `cat`, `cow` and `dog` keys are nested within `animals`. However, when the search results come back, none of the keys are nested, and are simply separated by `_`.

**My question is this:** Is there any way provided by Riak to "reverse format" the search, and return the fields of the object in the correct (nested) format? This becomes a problem when storing and returning user data that might possibly contain `_`.

I do see that the latest version of [Riak (beta release)](http://docs.basho.com/riak/latest/dev/advanced/search-schema/) provides a search schema, but I can't seem to see whether my question would be answered by this.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What you receive back in the search result is what the object looked like after passing through the json analyzer.  If you need the data formatted differently, you can use a custom analyzer.  However, this will only affect newly put data.

For existing data, you can use the `id` field and issue a get request for the original object, or use the solr query as input to a [MapReduce job](http://docs.basho.com/riak/latest/dev/using/search/#Query-Interfaces).

Comment: Thanks for the answer, Joe. Just one piece of clarification needed though - when you say to use the id and issue a get request, do you mean basically fetching the data, and then re-saving it? I don't see how just reading the data would cause the custom analyzer to come into play.

Comment: I mean when you want the data, use search to find the key and then get the value using a normal get so you have the original object to work with.

Comment: Ah, yeah, I did consider that. However, my only concern is that if there are 100 search results returned, we'd be making 101 Riak requests, as opposed to the 1 for the search only. Considering all the data is returned in the search, it makes sense to pull it from there if possible.